# Search for a specific string in all text files in all directories

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell. I am looking to search for a specific string in all text files in all directories. Here is my script but it is not searching sub directories.

```
Select-String -Path D:\FLAG_FILES\*.*  -Pattern "admin" | Out-File D:\logs\FLAG_FILES.txt
```

Comment: Please include change the code in the right format. `Example`

Answer (score 6):

`Select-String` doesn't have a `-Recurse` parameter. The workaround is to use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` and pipe to `Select-String`; e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\FLAG_FILES*.* -Recurse |
  Select-String "admin" | Out-File D:\logs\FLAG_FILES.txt
```

Comment: Hello Bill, The Above script is not searching sub directories. it is just searching the main directory

Comment: Run `Get-ChildItem D:\FLAG_FILES*.* -Recurse` by itself and see what it returns.